# babel-node: Syntax Error: Unexpected token import using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I am trying to run a node express app on my local machine for testing purposes using babel-node to transpile on the fly.  I created a server.js entry point file which contains the following code:

```
require("@babel/register")();

// Import the rest of our application.
module.exports = require('./bin/www');
```

Here is my package.json scripts entry to start up the application:

```
"testLocal": "nodemon --verbose --exec babel-node server.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:56746"
```

and I added a .babelrc file at the project root with the following code:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

The issue is that I continue to get the following error:

```
import cluster from 'cluster';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Here is the package from my package-json file, some I have removed to strip the code down to bare minimum example:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
"@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.11.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/register": "^7.11.5",
```

I found this example across several different articles but it does not seem to transpile.  I am using the babel-node on my local machine so I can transpile on the fly.  What am I missing in this setup that could cause this issue?

Comment: try ```babel-node ./bin/www``` not ```server.js```

Answer (score 0):

This is my `package.json` I am using `cross-env` to handle env, you can use `dotenv` ... and `pino` and `pino-pretty` for logs.

```
"scripts": {
    "nobuildprod": "pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --trace-warnings src/index.js  | pino-pretty",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir ./dist --source-maps --copy-files",

  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "pino": "^6.7.0",
    "pino-http": "^5.3.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.3.0",
  
  ...


  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.11.5",
```

server.js

```
require('@babel/register');
require('./src/index.js');
```

.babelrc ( i am using decorators )

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env"]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy" : true}]
    ],
    "env": {
        "development": {
          "sourceMaps": true,
          "retainLines": true
        }
    }
}
```

and ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'myapp',
      script: 'server.js',
      instances: 'max',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test',
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

so my source files are located in `./src`
I can run this app for dev, production using pm2, and making easy docker too.
I hope it be helpful for you.

Comment: I am still getting it, though I really like your approach.  I am moving to pm2 from Docker.  Debugging in Docker is a pain.  Are you using any import statements in your index.js file?

Comment: Logging in docker is not a pain, just use ```docker logs -f <conrainerName or ID>```
Yes I am using BABEL!

Comment: @user1790300 what is your ```nodejs``` version?